# Swift 4 - Xcode 9 beta 4 - NSKernAttributeName vs NSAttributedStringKey

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, xcode9-beta

iOS Deployment Target: iOS 9.3,
Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 11.0),
Xcode 9 Beta 4,
Swift 4

The following code builds and runs in Swift 3, Xcode 8:

```
    let kern = (CTRunGetAttributes(run) as? [String : Any])?
[NSKernAttributeName] as? CGFloat ?? 0
```

However, the Swift 4 migrator converts it to this:

```
    let kern = (CTRunGetAttributes(run) as? [String : Any])?
[NSAttributedStringKey.kern] as? CGFloat ?? 0
```

Xcode 9 now complains:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'NSAttributedStringKey'
```

According to the inspector, '`NSAttributedStringKey`' is only available in iOS 11. (Keep in mind that I am targeting iOS 9).

If I replace '`NSAttributedStringKey.kern`' with '`NSKernAttributeName`', the error remains.

Command-clicking on '`NSKernAttributeName`' tells me that its availability is iOS 6. However, the inspector also claims its type is '`NSAttributedStringKey`', which is only available in iOS 11. I do not know if this is merely an artefact of the API presentation, or a stuff-up, or something I'm missing.

Question: how can I use `NSKernAttributeName` (or its modernised version) with backward compatibility to iOS 9, with Swift 4?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type the dictionary as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] instead of [String : Any]. It's all sugar in the Swift overlay, so it should work even on older macOS/OS X versions.

EDIT: I should clarify my last sentence a bit. NSAttributedStringKey, as well as all the other new "Key" types in Swift 4, exists only in Swift and not in Objective-C. When a dictionary with NSAttributedStringKey keys gets bridged to Objective-C, all the keys will be turned into NSStrings. Since the actual Foundation, UIKit, etc. frameworks you're working with are written in C/Objective-C, this will "just work", and you don't have to worry about the documentation claiming NSAttributedStringKey is 10.11-only.

Comment: Thank you for that. And the explanation was much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
textField.defaultTextAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.kern.rawValue] = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

If you don't want to ignore the warning and cast regardless, you can copy them into a new dictionary cleanly.

```
var attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [:]
textField.defaultTextAttributes.forEach{
    attributes[NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: $0.key)] = $0.value
}
```